# Best approach to use when values are dynamically created?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit4

I'm looking for some advice on how to select a WebElement.
When I click a button that creates a new 'page', the given value is dynamic, in that it is totally random and not sequential. I would expect it to follow something like: page 1 = 0, page 2 = 1, page 3 = 2, etc.

By default I begin with a page, and its value is `c3`. Although when I trigger a button to create new pages the values appear as follows:

```
<select class="j-currentPage f-feature-A" name="currentPage">  <option value="c3">New Page</option>  <option value="c277">New Page 2</option>  <option value="c383">New Page 3</option>  <option selected="" value="c461">New Page 4</option>  </select>
```

So when I attempt to use the following:

```
 List<WebElement> option = chrome.findElements(By.tagName("option"));

    option.get(0).click();
    option.get(1).click();
    option.get(0).click();
```

It's obviously failing as the values are c277, c346 etc etc, and there is no way of knowing what the values will be in a new session as they will always be different.

The stacktrace is throwing a `StaleElementReferenceException` because its not in the DOM.

How can I select each page when the values are completely random?

I'm using Webdriver and JUnit4.

**EDIT**

Test method: to create some new pages.

```
@Test
public void createANewPage(){
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(chrome, 60);

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("select.j-currentPage.f-feature-A[name=\"currentPage\"]")));

    WebElement newPage = chrome.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.j-addViewBtn.ss-layers"));
    newPage.click();

    List<WebElement> option = chrome.findElements(By.tagName("option"));

    option.get(1).click();

    option.get(0).click();
}
```

Then a few tests later I want to call back the created page(s)

```
@Test
public void goToPage(){

    new WebDriverWait(chrome, 60).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("select.j-currentPage.f-feature-A[name=\"currentPage\"]")));
    List<WebElement> option = chrome.findElements(By.tagName("option"));

    option.get(0).click();
    option.get(1).click();
    option.get(0).click();
}
```

I receive a `org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException` at the point of the third `option.get(0).click();`

However I feel as though I'm approaching this the wrong way as the values are dynamically created `<option value="c3">New Page</option>

<option value="c207">New Page 2</option>

<option value="c288">New Page 3</option>

<option selected="" value="c366">New Page 4</option>`

Comment: One question here. Do you want to select any one of the option. Or a specific one?

Comment: I would like to have the ability to choose which ever page I want. So a specific page as I would like to switch between the pages in later tests.

Comment: I did not understood some points. Once you select an option will it forward to some other page you are asking "How can I select each page" so what exactly you want here is not clear. Can you please update your question with some more details.

Comment: My question is pretty clear. I want to know what is the best approach to take when selecting a web element that is given dynamic values. Values that will always be different for each session a user logs in, as stated in the question. Could the solution be around using `findElement(By.text("New Page 2")` ? But how could I select a specific page, e.g. using regex?

Answer (score 0):

The StaleElementReferenceException does not mean that it is not in the DOM.  It means that the DOM has changed since you found that object and therefore may be deleted or changed.  The change coudld be due to the page reloading or HTML refreshed via javascript.  Either way, Webdriver throws the error because it thinks it is probably good idea to refind objects as the page has changed.

If you refind the elements, then it will work.  You are finding by tag name, so the fact that ids have changed, should have no impact.

The following would work but does have performance issues;

```
chrome.findElements(By.tagName("option")).get(0).click
chrome.findElements(By.tagName("option")).get(1).click
chrome.findElements(By.tagName("option")).get(2).click
```

There will a better way to approach your problem for your particular application but hopefully understanding what stale elements actually indicates, will help you solve your issue.

Comment: do you perhaps have any examples to explain the startsWith, endsWith, contains methods? I have a feeling this could be the correct approach. Possibly using something like contains("New Page 2"); ?

Comment: To be honest, I don't completely understand your problem. Your list of web elements are found via TagName so differences in id will have no affect.  Can you confirm when you get the StaleElementException and the context within a test, perhaps even show the entire test method

Comment: I was asking what is the best approach to take when the application Im automating creates dynamic values. I think I was looking at this the wrong way. As you say, the ID/values should not matter, so instead I should be looking at using xpath, like so: `WebElement page1 = chrome.findElementByXPath("//option[contains(.,'New Page')]");
        page1.click();` and this has worked.

Answer (score 0):

None of the FindElement() strategies support using regular expressions for finding elements.

Though there is another way using regex, might help you

```
List<WebElement> option = chrome.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
```

now loop on the options and getText. Then do the regex check programmetically
Below is a demo code will not run. Please transfer it to jave

```
foreach(WebElement link in links)
{
    string text = link.Text;
    if (Regex.Match("your Regex here", text))
    {
        matchingLinks.Add(text);
    }
}

foreach(string linkText in matchingLinks) // now you have the texts even if they are dynamics
{
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.LinkText(linkText));
    element.Click();
    // do stuff on the page navigated to
    driver.Navigate().Back();
}
```

Comment: Css selectors have simple reg ex support for starts with, ends with and contains.  XPath also has these and possibly more

Comment: @APaul I wish I could say that this was very helpful, but I'm still do not have the solution to my question. Although I do appreciate you attempting to help.

Comment: yes css selector or xpath has its own regex support I am talking about "FindElement". No find element give any specific suppoty to find text match by regex. That is what I mean.

Comment: @Django_Tester : No worries. We are all here to help only :)

Answer (score 0):

OKay, I've just managed to solve the issue with the help of the contributors to this question.

It seems as though I just needed to use xpath instead of `List<WebElement>` so the below code now selects the pages I want.

```
@Test
public void jGoToPage(){

    new WebDriverWait(chrome, 60).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("select.j-currentPage.f-feature-A[name=\"currentPage\"]")));

    WebElement page1 = chrome.findElementByXPath("//option[contains(.,'New Page')]");
    page1.click();

    WebElement page2 = chrome.findElementByXPath("//option[contains(.,'New Page 2')]");
    page2.click();

    WebElement selectPage1Again = chrome.findElementByXPath("//option[contains(.,'New Page')]");

    selectPage1Again.click();
```

Perhaps not the best code, but if anyone would like to suggest a better way to refine it, please comment so others can learn.

The reason I declared `New Page` twice was because I was receiving a `staleElementReferenceException` again. So by simply attempting to perform `page1.click();` immediately after `page2.click();` is when that happened which is why I declared it as `selectPage1Again`

I also used this [question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2485/webdriver-find-elements-by-text?rq=1) to help with the solution.